# Where should I post questions about natural resources?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should I post questions about natural resources, especially their economic aspects?

Comment: I don't believe there _is_ a current Stack Exchange that will do, though there is a [Green Energy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5167/green-energy) proposal.

Comment: Uhh...in what regards? There was an economics SE but it was closed.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your specific question, we can only guess. However, [Economics Stack Exchange](https://economics.stackexchange.com/) (created a few years after this Meta question) has some questions about natural resources like [oil](https://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=oil), [iron](https://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=iron), etc. As always, check the relevant articles in their help center before posting: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

For the use of natural resources on a smaller scale, consider [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/).